# Why are Python, Ruby, and Node.js so much slower than Bash, AWK, Perl?

Tags: python, node.js, ruby

While making a polyglot makefile (which launches many thousands of processes), I noticed that scripting languages vary *enormously* in their start-up performance.

---

Bash

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time bash -c "echo 'hello world'" > /dev/null
0.002
```

AWK

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time awk "BEGIN { print \"hello world\" }" > /dev/null
0.002
```

Perl

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time perl -e "print \"hello world\n\"" > /dev/null
0.003
```

All those are essentially the same. But then each of these scripting languages are an order of magnitude(!) slower.

Python

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time python -c "print 'hello world'" > /dev/null
0.023
```

Ruby

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time ruby -e "puts 'hello world'" > /dev/null
0.024
```

Node.js

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time node -e "console.log('hello world')" > /dev/null
0.082
```

What sorts of things are Python, Ruby, and Node.js doing to make them so much slower than the equivalent Bash, AWK, and Perl programs? Is it just the way things turned out, or is there something more fundamental about their design that make them have so much more overhead?

Comment: Ruby loads gems, try `ruby --disable-gems -e "..."`

Answer (score 7):

In your examples, you are practically only measuring how much they take to start.
So, those slowest 3 are the slowest because their interpreters do more at the beginning, but not necessarily that means in a long running program they will be slower.

You can write some long running examples (where you do thousands of calculations), then you can see which one is actually slowest in the long run.

Bear in mind that each of those is meant for different things, so it's likely one of them will be very fast for processing files (`awk`) while others will be very fast at doing 10s of things simultaneously (`Node.js`).

Comment: Sure. But I'm not running long-running programs. I'm running lots of short-running programs. (That's how make works.) I don't think this an answer.

Comment: Since you didn't specify which implementations you are using, it is impossible to say what those implementations are doing that may impact their startup performance. JRuby, for example, will typically first start up a JVM (which includes a *huge* standard library and may or may not include an interpreter and/or multiple compilers), then start up JRuby, then start up a JRuby instance, which in turn includes an interpreter, two compilers, and a rather large runtime library, and last but not least will load the Ruby core library (which is also rather large), which in turn includes RubyGems.

Comment: Seems there is some speed difference in large input as well FWIW: https://brenocon.com/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/ but that doesn't stop me from preferring ruby :)